# Terminal Doesn't Open After Install

Tags: virtualbox, gnome-terminal

I recently followed the [steps here to install Ubuntu Desktop virtual machine using VirtualBox 7](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-run-ubuntu-desktop-on-a-virtual-machine-using-virtualbox#1-overview) using the *Unattended Guest OS Install* feature with the *Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS* image. Once I start the VM for the first time post-install, the terminal app won't open. (See GIF below).

[image]

If I access a failsafe TTY terminal with `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `F3`, I can run `apt update`, `apt upgrade` and `snap refresh` and reboot successfully but that doesn't solve my problem.

How can I resolve this issue? Are there potential error logs that I could look at? Is this a known issue somewhere?

Comment: Any errors in `~/.xsession-errors`?

Comment: Did you verify the image had no errors? https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview

Comment: @popey No `~/.xsession-errors` exists

Comment: @David Image Verifies as OK.

Comment: try using `konsole` by `sudo apt install konsole && konsole &` or `gnome-console` by `sudo apt-get install gnome-console -y && sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator x-terminal-emulator /usr/bin/kgx 1 && sudo update-alternatives --config x-terminal-emulator && gnome-console &`

Comment: This is likely a GPU issue. Do any applications at all load? Are you using Wayland or xorg in the session?

Comment: @popey Other applications load fine. (e.g. Konsole & Firefox). The problem exists in both Wayland & xorg sessions.

Answer (score 0):

One possible workaround that worked for me is to install `konsole` via `apt install konsole` and then to use that instead of the built in terminal. (The built in terminal can then be removed with `apt remove gnome-terminal`)